# WinAppDriver/WebDriver screenshot - How to take screenshot of only one desktop(primary monitor)?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, winappdriver

I'm trying to take a full-screen screenshot using WinAppDriver. Since WinAppDriver comes from WebDriver, I created a Desktop session like this:

```
    var options = new AppiumOptions();
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("app", "Root");
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", PcName);
    var desktopSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(Uri), options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOutInSeconds));
```

And then simply use this line to get the screenshot:

```
Screenshot screenshot = desktopSession.GetScreenshot();
```

This works nearly all the time but the catch is: I work on two monitors so it also takes screenshot of other screen too.

Is there a way to **take a screenshot** of  **only the primary monitor** in WinAppDriver?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, it is not. The "Desktop" covers both screens in that scenario. Alternatively you can take a screenshot from one application only, if that application is the root point of your Session.

In general i would recommend you to ask WinAppDriver related questions in thier github repo
where the community is active:
https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues

Or you go for a workaround like, take the screenshot, convert to image, cut the image in half (= cut off all pixels from the screen you dont want), save the cropped image.

Hope i could help